# Makefile 'undefined reference' error

Tags: c++, reference, makefile, undefined

I am working on an IRC-Bot and I am at the point of running 'make' on a bot that is already finished and I want to possibly modify.
However, I get the following 'undefined reference' error:

```
g++  -g -O2 -lpthread  -o markovsky-irc markovsky.o markovutil.o markovsky-irc.o botnet.o dcc_chat.o dcc_send.o output.o server.o utils.o  
botnet.o: In function `BN_getthreadspecific':
/home/bavor/Applications/markovsky-0.53/botnet/botnet.c:113: undefined reference to `pthread_once'
/home/bavor/Applications/markovsky-0.53/botnet/botnet.c:114: undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
/home/bavor/Applications/markovsky-0.53/botnet/botnet.c:119: undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
botnet.o: In function `BN_Connect':
/home/bavor/Applications/markovsky-0.53/botnet/botnet.c:154: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
botnet.o: In function `BN_tsinitkey':
/home/bavor/Applications/markovsky-0.53/botnet/botnet.c:95: undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
dcc_chat.o: In function `BN_AcceptDCCChat':
/home/bavor/Applications/markovsky-0.53/botnet/dcc_chat.c:216: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
dcc_chat.o: In function `BN_SendDCCChatRequest':
/home/bavor/Applications/markovsky-0.53/botnet/dcc_chat.c:97: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
dcc_chat.o: In function `BN_AcceptDCCChat':
/home/bavor/Applications/markovsky-0.53/botnet/dcc_chat.c:217: undefined reference to `pthread_detach'
dcc_chat.o: In function `BN_SendDCCChatRequest':
/home/bavor/Applications/markovsky-0.53/botnet/dcc_chat.c:98: undefined reference to `pthread_detach'
dcc_send.o: In function `BN_SendDCCSendRequest':
/home/bavor/Applications/markovsky-0.53/botnet/dcc_send.c:102: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
dcc_send.o: In function `BN_AcceptDCCSend':
/home/bavor/Applications/markovsky-0.53/botnet/dcc_send.c:245: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
dcc_send.o: In function `BN_SendDCCSendRequest':
/home/bavor/Applications/markovsky-0.53/botnet/dcc_send.c:103: undefined reference to `pthread_detach'
dcc_send.o: In function `BN_AcceptDCCSend':
/home/bavor/Applications/markovsky-0.53/botnet/dcc_send.c:246: undefined reference to `pthread_detach'
utils.o: In function `BN_UnsetSigs':
/home/bavor/Applications/markovsky-0.53/botnet/utils.c:257: undefined reference to `pthread_sigmask'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [markovsky-irc] Error 1
```

I don't know if I need to show the Makefile here, since it is pretty long.
I have searched for this error already but I couldnt really find anything that could help me resolve this error and I was hoping to find some individual help here. Thanks!

edit: ./configure output:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: executing depfiles commands
```

Comment: You have to put `-lpthread` at the **end** of the linker invocation.

Comment: I just run the 'make' command, how do I specify that it puts it at the end? Also, I copypasted the 'g++ ...' command and ran it manually and now its giving me a 'mutliple definition error'

Comment: @userXXX modify your Makefile using a... wait for it... ***text editor!***

Comment: I guess it is the same thing if I copy-paste the command line the gives the error and manually put -lpthread at the end, which is what I did and it still does not work, because now it gives me the multiple references error message.

Comment: Did the `./configure` command output any error? Also, what platform are you compiling on?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I will edit my question and show the configure output in case you need it.

Comment: Also, what platform are you compiling on? (sorry, I did edit my question just after you did answer it)

Comment: No problem :) At first I used mingw and now its on Linux version 3.13.0-5-generic, didn't work for both platforms (gave the same errors).

Comment: Strange, I just built it for Linux 3.2.46 without any errors. But rather than the Linux version (which is barely the kernel), could you tell what is the environment against which you try to build please (personally, I've used Debian wheezy)? :)

Comment: Well it is only a bash running on a vps, not really an environment. So you just ran ./configure and make right after without modifying anything? strange.

Comment: What I call environment here is the collection of libraries that can be used to build your program with. Also, a "VPS" is a very vague information, since many (very) different technologies exist for running virtual appliances (KVM, [Xen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xen), [LXC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXC), for example, to quote only three that are running totally differently), and while I see why building a software on a Xen VM would not be very different from building a software on a bare machine; I also see why using LXC for the same purpose could complicate the things substantially.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your reply; I have to apologize because my knowledge is not that big when it comes to makefiles etc. Is there a way for me to see which environment I use?

Comment: @user2308896 : check `uname -a`, also check if you have `rpm` or `apt`, and if you have `apt`, you could also check what is in your `/etc/apt/source.list` file. That would help to know what environment you have. For the visualization part, just [try what's here](http://www.dmo.ca/blog/detecting-virtualization-on-linux/).

Comment: thats what uname -a gives: `Linux vm-0.bavor.koding.kd.io 3.13.0-5-generic #20 SMP Mon Jan 20 19:56:12 PST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: thats what in the `sourcelist: deb http://apt-mirror.in.koding.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://apt-mirror.in.koding.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://apt-mirror.in.koding.com/ubuntu/ raring-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://dev.marc.waeckerlin.org/repo raring main
# deb-src http://dev.marc.waeckerlin.org/repo raring main
deb http://apt-mirror.in.koding.com/nodejs/ raring main`

Comment: Okay so you are using ubuntu raring. Please consider upgrading to saucy while trusty isn't released yet, to avoid any upgrade problems (Ubuntu upgrades are best done against close versions). Also, since you are using a VPS, could you tell what technology it uses? Xen? KVM? OpenVZ (<- more likely)? LXC? This information, in the event you can't find it with the methods described in the link from my previous comment, is probably on the website of your VPS provider.

Comment: I cant seem to find it anywhere on the site, also it denies my permission when I try to find out via command line with the description in the link you gave me (neither it does work with sudo) :(

Comment: Okay, I just found out that it is using LXC.

Comment: Okay. From [the job offer](http://koding.github.io/jobs/systems-guru/) they have on their website, I would say: LXC. Therefore, depending on how it is setup, it would be best for you to compile your code somewhere else, then use it on your VM (not sure it will work tho). Best would be to setup a Linux virtual machine on your local host, using [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) for example, and build markovsky in it.

Comment: Yeah I just need a compiled version of it so that it runs at least on my PC, the rest is easily sorted out. I will try to do it with virtualbox, although it feels weird I can't do it directly with minGW.

Answer (score 1):

Your platform's documentation should specify how to correctly get POSIX pthreads support. For most Linux distributions, you pass the `-pthread` flag to both the compiler and the linker. Typically, the compiler flag does nothing but the linker flag links to the pthreads library.

Do not use `-lpthread`. It's not portable, and in the future more than just linking to the library might be needed. For example, passing `-DTHREAD_SAFE` to the compiler might be required on some platforms.

Comment: If i'm doing it on windows with mingw, do you know how it works there?

Comment: I already used `pthread` instead of `lpthread` both in the beginning and in the end of the command and it is not working both cases.